# Change the font size/color of the values displayed inside the pie chart using chartjs

Tags: chart.js, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Can the font size/color of the values displayed inside the pie chart be changed which is built using Chart.js?

[image: Attached the image of the chart below]

Comment: Yes. If you're using `datalabels` plugin, through its `font` option. Please share your code so we can tell you something specific.

Comment: Hi @kikon,  I have used chartjs library to display the chart and chartjspluginlabels plugin for displaying the values inside the chart. Below is the code used to print the values on the chart.
options: {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {labels:{render:(args)=>{
  return args.value;
  }}},
}

Comment: Well, I was thinking more on the lines of a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
One's questions are much more likely to get a good answer fast if they include the code that is responsible for your issues in a way that it can be pasted by others in their IDEs so they can immediately experience your issues themselves. A js fiddle or a codepen can be a solution if the code is too complicated, but in that case it's still a good idea to include a part of the code in the question itself.

Comment: As for the fragment you included, it seems to me you are using [chart-js-plugin-labels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-labels).
On its [demo page](https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/) you can look up the fourth example, that changes `fontSize`, `fontStyle`, `fontColor`,  and `fontFamily`. Also, I'd recommend to switch to [`chart-js-plugin-datalabels`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) which is a newer, recommended and maintained plugin for displaying labels on pie and other types of charts.